# Rewrite all urls to secure index

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am currently using this code in my .htaccess to route all traffic to SSL

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Because this is also a single landing page, I would also like to route urls such as www.example.com/testing, www.example.com/?testing=anything,etc back to the index page https://www.example.com

Answer (score 1):

just remove the "$1" part, so it will be:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/ [R,L]
```

Comment: did you replaced "https://www.example.com/" with your domain name? Did you tried if it's working "https://<your domain name>/" ?

If you will replace "https://www.example.com/" with "https://google.com" you will see that it's working

Also you can write like this:
`RewriteRule . https://www.example.com/ [L]`